# Why can't I get the article data from this structure?

Tags: javascript

I've been scratching my head over this problem all day.

I made a change removing the inline data and instead added a getJSON function. However on doing this none of the data renders in the modal, and I can't figure out where the issue is.

I'm expecting a modal which displays a set of articles titles and links within the modal.

The data on the gist page shows all keys in the json payload having double quotes.

```
"articles": [{
        "title": "Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Black Hole Merger",
        "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
        "url": "https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102"
    },
    {
        "title": "First observation of gravitational waves",
        "publishDate": "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves"
    },
    {
        "title": "Gravitational Waves Detected 100 Years After Einstein's Prediction",
        "publishDate": "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
        "url": "https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20160211"
    }
]
```

However, using `console.log` on what is retrieved reveals that the keys do not have quotes:

```
articles: [
    {
        publishDate: "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
        title: "Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Black Hole Merger",
        url: "https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102"
    },
    {
        publishDate: "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
        title: "First observation of gravitational waves",
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves"
    },
    {
        publishDate: "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
        title: "Gravitational Waves Detected 100 Years After Einstein's Prediction",
        url: "https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20160211"
    }
]
```

```js
const getJSON = async url => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
            if (!response.ok) { // check if response worked (no 404 errors etc...)
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }

        const data = await response.json(); // get JSON from the response

        return data; // returns a promise, which resolves to this data value
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        //return error;
    }
}

console.log("Fetching data...");
getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TheMightyLlama/9f4f1b4c2c078a6080c9212aba6beb59/raw/News%2520Detail%2520Sample%2520-%2520Ligo.json")
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);

        function getArrayByName(name) {
            return data.filter(
                function(data) {
                    return item[name];
                }
            )[0][name];
        }

        //POPULATES YOUTUBE LIST
        //Carousel indicators
        //Carousel inners
        //Carousel left and right controls

        //POPULATES ARTICLES LIST
        var article = getArrayByName('articles');

        var listgroup = document.createElement("ul");
        listgroup.setAttribute("class", "list-group list-group-flush");

        for (var r in article) {
            var listitem = document.createElement("li");
            listitem.setAttribute("class", "list-group list-group-item");

            //var itemicon = document.createElement("i");
            //itemicon.setAttribute("class","far fa-newspaper");

            var itemlink = document.createElement("a");
            itemlink.setAttribute("href", article[r].url);
            itemlink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            itemlink.innerHTML = article[r].title;

            //listitem.appendChild(itemicon);
            listitem.appendChild(itemlink);
            listgroup.appendChild(listitem);

            var element = document.getElementById("argroup");
            element.appendChild(listgroup);
        }
    });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/litera/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    a.list-item-scheduled {
      background: #F0F0F0;
    }
    
    a.list-item-unscheduled {
      background: #FF5555;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Open Modal</button>

  <h6>
    Youtube
  </h6>
  <div class="list-group container" id="ytgroup"></div>

  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="mymodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#FF5555;color:#FFFFFF">

          <h4 class="modal-title" name="modal-title"></h4><i class="fas fa-bookmark" style="color:#FFCC00"></i>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!--POPULATED BY JS SLIDER-->
          <!--POPULATED BY JS GETARRAYBYNAME-->
          <div class="list-group container" id="argroup"></div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add _console.log_ statements, and print debug statements to the console. See if your code is actually executing the proper loops with the proper variables.

Comment: You've made quite a bold assertion in the title. Bold assertions require bold evidence, which is lacking in the question. Please [edit] the question to include an example of what the service returns that you claim isn't getting parsed correctly by JavaScript.

Comment: What should happen? What _is_ happening? What errors are you seeing in the console? Also, your provided code snippet isn't even running.

Comment: The data you are fetching is a JSON object, yet you are applying `data.filter()` on it, which is for filtering arrays ... And even if your `data` was an array, the way you are using it, suggests, you don't really have a clue on how to use is properl. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Note that the function `getArrayByName` defines a function passed to  `filter` and names its only argument `data`, yet the body of the function uses an undefined variable named `item`. I don't see how that would work. You should be getting an error in the console about that...

Comment: Replace `var article = getArrayByName('articles');` with `var article = data.articles;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getArrayByName` function is not correct. The returned data is a single object, not an array of objects. The object has a single `articles` property, you should just return that property.

```
function getArrayByName(name) {
  return data[name];
}
```

It hardly even seems necessary to have a function for this. Just write

```
var articles = data.articles;
```

What your function apparently tries to do is return all the elements of the `data` array with a non-empty `articles` property. But it won't work because `data` isn't an array, so it doesn't have a `filter()` method. And Then you're accessing the nonexistent variable `item` instead of the callback parameter `data` (and it's also confusing to use the same name for the callback parameter as the array you're filtering).

Comment: Ok, so this has helped. I'm still not able to loop through `articles` as you've demonstrated above. But this is one step clear that I'm happy to take.

Comment: I also had a miss-named variable `article` instead of `articles` in the loop. So that's all done. Thank you!